# Insert blocking update query on table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table "Alert_List" with two sessions are running on it.

**Session 1**:

```
insert into Alert_List values ( "required values")
```

**Session 2**:

```
Update A
set Active = 0
from Alert_List A
left join STG_Alert B on A.Alert_List_Id = B.Alert_List_Id
left join STG_UserID C on A.UserID = C.UserID
where B.Alert_List_Id is null and C.UserID is null
```

Here `STG_Alert,STG_UserID`are staging tables which will have a few selected `Alert_List_Id` and `UserID` which are not required to be deactivated.

Indexes on Alert_List as below.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Alert_List] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_EA_List] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Alert_List_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Alert_List_INDEX] ON [dbo].[Alert_List]
(
    [AVE_Id] ASC,
    [Request_Id] ASC,
    [User_Id] ASC,
    Active ASC,
    [Process_Id] ASC,
    [Status_Id] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Alert_List_Id]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [indexeaml] ON [dbo].[Alert_List]
(
    [User_Id] ASC,
    [Process_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

One query from above two failing with below error.

> Transaction (Process ID 85) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

I dont want to use `WITH(NOLOCK)` nor `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` in this case.

Let me know if you have any other ways to solve this issue.

Comment: Show full transactions code.

Comment: also show deadlock xml and schema of tables involved along with indexes

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `UPDATE` will change all but a few in the Alert_List table.  This will likely require a full scan and is prone to deadlocks, especially with other multi-statement transactions.

Comment: You say you don't want to use `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION`, but why not? It's the first thing I thought of when I read your question title

Comment: Turn on sql profiler. Check open connections to the database and also trace commands. If you're using some orm you might be getting some implicit updates after insert or something else.

Comment: `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` will use tempdb heavily. so we cant afford it.

Comment: I am running this queries on backup db, with one Job enabled which insert records into table(i.e. session 1). I think no need to use sql profiler. @doker